# Android DDMS screen capture, changing the size of image

Tags: screenshot, ddms

When i am capturing the screen shot using DDMS, the default image dimention is 480*200. Can we change this dimention?

i want the captured image in small size (dimention).

I know i can do it later with any photo editor. but i need to take several screen shots and changing each captured image will be an extra overhead for me, so looking for some direct solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While possibly not the answer you are looking for, you could capture them all in the default size and then use a batch image resizer like Irfanview (if you are in Windows) to resize everything on one shot.